# Applying changes to Prefab Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have problem with applying changes to Prefab. As you see in the screenshot I can't press the *Apply All*  button, but when I click *Revert All* everything seems to be working. Do you have any ideas what could fix it? I'm using Unity 2019.

Inspector view:

[image: Inspector view]

I expected to apply changes made in scene to my Prefab and every instance.

Comment: It is possible to make your changes in the prefab-editormode? What changes did you want to make to the prefab? PS: Is it a model from another tool?

Comment: Changes i made is making collider triggerable. Its a prefabs from kenney's pack. Its possible to make changes on prefab itself but its hard - when i try to set collider on exact position or have preview of changes i cant open it in unity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are actually editing the .fbx directly, and I believe you can't do that.
What we do when we import from Blender/3DS Max/Whatever is :

1 - Drag the fbx in your scene.

2 - Right click on the object in the hierarchy : unpack prefab completly.

3 - Do what you want to do on the object

4 - Drag your object into your assets

Now you have a "real" prefab and can do whatever you want to with it

Comment: You're welcome ! Please set the answer as accepted :)